# 'arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow' when typing over 10 numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that handles continuous numbering for receipts. everything works fine when inputting our receipt numbers. lately we accepted centers where they process payments for our company. Their number seems to be very long. when inputted this throws the "arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error. I have noticed that this only occurs if the number's length is higher than ten.

```
    Dim input As String = InputBox("New ORNo", "Sequence No", ORNoTextBox.Text)
    Try
        For i = 0 To input.Length - 1
            If IsNumeric(input.Chars(i)) = False Then
                MsgBox("Please Input a Valid Sequence No", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Input")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
        MsgBox("Please Input a Valid Sequence No", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Input")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim integerInput As Double = Double.Parse(input.Trim)
    Try
        ORPaymentsDB.DBConnect("ConcessionairesAccnt")

        integerInput -= 1
        ORPaymentsDB.ExecuteSQL("Update Counter set SeqNo=@0 Where CCode=@1", integerInput, CounterCode)

    Catch ex As Exception
        ORPaymentsDB.rollback()
        ORPaymentsDB.CloseDB()
        MsgBox("Error Saving ORNo" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, "Error...")
        Exit Sub
    Finally

    End Try
```

Comment: It is likely that the sequence number in your database is defined as a 32-bit integer. In that case, the highest value it will accept is 2,147,483,647 (which has 10 decimal digits). If you want to accept a higher number than that, your database will need to use something else (perhaps a 64-bit integer).

Comment: You can also replace all that validation code with a `TryParse` method. For example to accept only a valid integer that will fit in a 64-bit integer, use `Dim integerInput As Long` followed by `If Not Long.TryParse(input, integerInput) Then` If the input string can be converted to a 64-bit integer, `TryParse` will do that and store the result in `integerInput`, otherwise it will return false and you can display an error message.

Comment: @Blackwood thank you for clarifying that. I thought my problem lies in my code. I changed my database column from int to numeric(18,0) and it worked

Comment: It seems odd that the receipt number would be a numeric type.  Are you doing calculations with this number?  It seems like it should be a varchar type.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway in our company we use the pre-printed receipts that came from the national printing office. so per receipt we need to iterate the receipt number (which are all numbers somehow) for the next transaction so that the teller does not need to input it per transaction. just the first one at the beginning of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my database column from int to numeric(18,0) and it worked.

Relied mainly on sir *Blackwood*'s comment

> It is likely that the sequence number in your database is defined as a 32-bit integer. In that case, the highest value it will accept is 2,147,483,647 (which has 10 decimal digits). If you want to accept a higher number than that, your database will need to use something else (perhaps a 64-bit integer)